# Proper way to deal with images (html, css)?

Tags: html, css

so I'm messing around with jsfiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/3mfnckuv/3/

For those of you who play Destiny, this is Destiny inspired haha..

but anyway, a few questions :)

1) Why is there the white space underneath the image?

2) I'm trying to put the image and description side by side. I wrapped the image in a div, then used inline block, rather than float. Is this a good approach?

3) How can I move the description div, higher and align it with the top edge of the picture?

4) I removed whitespace caused by inline-bock using margin-left: -4px. Is this a good approach?

5) Is it a good practice to set width and height to 100% on the body and html?

```
<ul class="test-2">
    <li>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/9/92/Invective_icon.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150912145552" alt="invective" width="50px" height="50px"></div>
        <p>Invective</p>
     </li>
 </ul>

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.test-2 li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.image, p {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: too many questions, most of them opinion based..

Comment: inline-block is a funny thing. If you want that space removed, get rid of the line break in the code. </div><p> and then you won't need the -4px. height:100% on body wont do anything as is. and ultimately, if it works then I wouldn't worry about inline-block vs float.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why is there the white space underneath the image?

The default `vertical-align` of your image is `baseline` by default.  Change it to `top`, `bottom`, or `middle` to get rid of the white space.

> 2) I'm trying to put the image and description side by side. I wrapped the image in a div, then used inline block, rather than float. Is this a good approach?

Sure.  White space in your HTML between the image and the text will be rendered as white space on your page when using `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.  With `float: left`, the white space is collapsed.

> 3) How can I move the description div, higher and align it with the top edge of the picture?

Set the `vertical-align: top` on the element containing the text.

> 4) I removed whitespace caused by inline-bock using margin-left: -4px. Is this a good approach?

No.  That white space is an actual space character.  Collapse it using `float: left` or remove it from your html.

> 5) Is it a good practice to set width and height to 100% on the body and html?

Maybe.  Won't hurt.  This was a trick that helped columns fill the page.  Today we can just set `min-height: 100vh` instead.  The `vh` and `vw` units, representing view height and view width, respectively, are very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Here I think I fixed your problems. Try this out. You needed to make your image class in the img tag. Also I put your p tag inside the same div as the image.

Here is CSS

```
 body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.test-2 li {
list-style-type: none;
}

p {
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
left: 110px;
}

.image {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here is the div in HTML

```
<div><img class="image" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/9/92/Invective_icon.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150912145552" alt="invective" width="50px" height="50px"><p>Invective</p></div>
```

Also when using css you don't have to put html for the body just body will do fine.